# Getting strings out of an dynamic array

Tags: php, arrays

```
foreach ($_GET['friend_name'] as $id => $key) {
    if (!empty($_GET['friend_vorname'][$id])) {
        var_dump($_GET['friend_anrede_'.$id][0]);
        $msg .= 'Anrede: ' . $_SESSION['friend_anrede'][$id][$id] .'<br>Vorname: ' 
              . $_GET['friend_vorname'][$id] . '<br>Name: '
              . $_GET['friend_name'][$id] . '<br>Strasse / Nr.: '
              . $_GET['friend_strasse_nr'][$id] . '<br>PLZ / Ort: '
              . $_GET['friend_plz_ort'][$id] . '<br><br>';
    }
}
```

The var_dump() returns:

> string(4) "Frau" string(4) "Herr" string(4) "Frau"

I would now like to use the single stings for my variable `$msg` just like all the other variables.

I thought `$_SESSION['friend_anrede'][$id][$id]` would make it but it only returns:

> F

I would be very glad if someone could get me out of this array labyrinth!

Comment: I am not sure if your question is entirely clear but what should be the output that you are looking for ?

Comment: What if you change `$_SESSION['friend_anrede'][$id][$id]`to `$_SESSION['friend_anrede'][$id]`? Not either sure I understand, though.

Comment: @Maximus2012 since the foreach will loop 3 times. The values should look like this: 1. Frau, 2: Herr, 3: Frau ... just the same as the result of var_dump but not as an array.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson `$_SESSION['friend_anrede'][$id]` only returns: Frau

Answer (score 3):

All you need is `$_SESSION['friend_anrede'][$id]`. Remember that PHP allows you to treat a string as an array of characters, like this

```
$foo = 'Hello';
echo $foo[1]; // outputs 'e'
```

So your `$_SESSION['friend_anrede'][$id][$id]` was dumping out the 0th-character of the 0th-element in your `friend_anrede` array:

```
$_SESSION['friend_anrede'][$id][$id]
^------ 'Frau' ---------------^[0]
'Frau'[0] -> 'F'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My variable `$_GET['friend_anrede']` looks a bit different, since there are multiple variables which look like this: $_GET['friend_anrede_0'], $_GET['friend_anrede_1'], $_GET['friend_anrede_2'] etc. The numbers at the end are getting added dynamically. I think that must be the point of my issue.

Comment: it's php. there's no need for creating dynamic "keys" like that. you can use the array-notation naming hack `<input ... name="friend_anrede[0]"`, and then you'll get an array in `$_GET['friend_anrede']`.